# Primeng Autocomplete Component overlay panel element expanding above autocomplete bar: How can I suggestions panel overlay expand only below

Tags: angular, primeng

I've been attempting to style the PrimeNg Autocomplete component so when a user is interacting with it, and suggestions begin to populate, the suggestions overlay panel will only display underneath the primeNg autocomplete component.

Here's a visual of the problem:
[image]

I've been trying to style the component, as well as add various properties in attmept to make this work. Any suggestions? Here is component properties: [text](https://primeng.org/autocomplete#api.autocomplete.props.readonly)

Here is html of component:

```
<p-autoComplete
  class="custom-auto-complete"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedResult"
  [suggestions]="results"
  (completeMethod)="search($event)"
  (onSelect)="route($event)"
  [minLength]="3"
  [showClear] = true
  [autoHighlight] = "true"
  [placeholder] = "placeHolder"
  [style]="{'width':'100%',
  'height':'100%','font-size':'18px'}"
  [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%','font-size':'18px'}"
  [panelStyle]="{'font-size':'18px'}"
  
></p-autoComplete>
```

The component exists in navsearch div. Here are the styles of this parent component:

```
.navsearch {


  margin-top: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 65px;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

I've tried combinations of CSS and applying properties to the component, but nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

You can set the top property manually for overly by do the following:

1- implements `AfterViewChecked` hook.

2- Inject `NgZone` in your component.

3- Add template reference on the `<p-autocomplete>` and read it using `@ViewChild`:

`@ViewChild('autoComplete') autoComplete: AutoComplete;`

4- Inside the `ngAfterViewChecked()` do the following:

```
   this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      if (this.autoComplete.overlay) {
        this.autoComplete.overlay.style.top = '50px';
      }
    });
```

this is the full code:
TS:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  @ViewChild('autoComplete') autoComplete: AutoComplete;

  constructor(
    private ngZone: NgZone
  ) {}
  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      if (this.autoComplete.overlay) {
        this.autoComplete.overlay.style.top = '50px';
      }
    });
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<p-autoComplete
  #autoComplete
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry"
  [suggestions]="filteredCountries"
  (completeMethod)="filterCountry($event)"
  field="name"
  [minLength]="1"
></p-autoComplete>
```

#### Update for PrimeNG 16:

use `overlayViewChild` instead of `overlay` and change the top for `overlayEl`

```
export class AutocompleteBasicDemo implements AfterViewChecked {
  @ViewChild('autocomplete') autocomplete: AutoComplete;
  constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }
  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      if (this.autocomplete.overlayViewChild.overlayEl) {
        (
          this.autocomplete.overlayViewChild.overlayEl as HTMLElement
        ).style.top = '90px'; // edit the top value as your use case
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me...

Comment: Could you please adjust the top value to `-180px` in my previous answer? I provided an example to illustrate how to adjust the overlay position of the autocomplete component.

Comment: Are you using an older PrimeNG version? autoComplete.overlay is undefined. Using PrimeNG 16 and .overlay doesn't exist. I see overlayViewChild, overlayOptions, etc.

Comment: I'm so sorry I use older version. I update the answer for version 16 now that should work with you I tested it and it will work as expected. thanks.